# How to restructure a multidimenstional array

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I am new to PHP and I am dealing with some array problems.

I have an array with song lists.

That looks something like this

```
0 =>[
    "song" => "Hey Brother"
    "artists" => array:1 [ …1]
]
1 =>[
    "song" => "Do I Wanna Know?"
    "artists" => array:1 [ …1]
]
2 =>[
    "song" => "House Party - Airplay Edit"
    "artists" => array:4 [ …4]
]
```

Now i can loop over the array like this to only get the song names

```
foreach ($songList as $song) {
   $songName[] = $song['song'];
}
```

But my endGoal would be so save in a variable like `$fullSongName`the song name and the Artists next to each other.
And i can't really figure out how to do it.

***EDIT:***

Here is how the artists array looks like if i dump `$songs`

```
"artists" => array:1 [
    0 => "Avicii"
]
```

Or if I dump  `$song['artists']` (which is the same)

```
array:1 [
    0 => "Avicii"
]
```

***Note:*** There are (obviously) some cases with multiple artists.

Comment: Acctualy kida , but i dont understand, why don't i have to loop over the arrays ? Also since i am in a class, i have to do it like this ```array_map(array($this,'implodeIt')``` . This solution is very good but my idea was ```fullSongName' => 'songname + artist' ```     ==> Beacuse i want to write at the end all the results in a file and it would be much eayser that way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on what we discussed in comment, apply a `foreach()` loop and concatenate song name with artist name like below:

```
$finalArray =[];
 foreach($songList as $songLst){
    $finalArray[] = $songLst['song'].'-'.trim(implode(',',$songLst['artists']));
 }

 print_r($finalArray);
```

Output: https://3v4l.org/cjOEJ

Answer (score 0):

I am making some assumptions, but here you go:

```
$songs =  [[
  "song" => "Hey Brother",
  "artists" => ["Avicii"]
  ],
  [
    "song" => "Do I Wanna Know?",
    "artists" => ["Artist 1", "Artist 2"]
  ],
  [
    "song" => "House Party - Airplay Edit"
    "artists" => ["Avicii", "Dumbledore band", "The Hobbits"]
  ]];


$result = array_map($songs, function($s){
// Join everything in artists array in a comma separated string and add the song name
return join(", ",$s["artists"])." - ".$s["song"];
});
```

The result will look like:

```
[
"Avici - Hey Brother",
"Artist 1, Artist 2 - Do I wanna know?",
"Avicii, Dumbledore band, The Hobbits - House Party - Airplay Edit"
]
```